# Converting floating ratios to int

Tags: python, math

I need to convert float ratios to their integer equivalent

0.5:1 ---should convert to ---> 1:2

0.5:0.6:1 ---should convert to ---> 5:6:10 (smallest integer ratio)

My googling produced no results in this regard

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. If you want people to do your homework you should offer some compensation.

Comment: None of answers here is a solution, bcs they are converting them to int fractions not int ratios, this problem is solvable by a lp solver but that would be like using too much fire power for such small task

Comment: @Manish I reedited my answer, added functional C++ code (sorry not a python coder) with more in depth descripthion how to approach this. Anyway if you really want to have `0.5/0.6/1 -> 5/6/10` then you need to add/specify target accuracy limits... what is the range of the floats? haw many decimals are considered stil viable number etc ... otherwise the magnitude of the results will be big for numbers not representable by a sum of powers of two ...

Answer (score 9):

`float.as_integer_ratio`:

```
In [1064]: f = .5                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [1065]: f.as_integer_ratio()                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[1065]: (1, 2)
```

Comment: 0.5:0.6:1 ---should convert to ---> 5:6:10 (smallest integer ratio)

Comment: This does not answer the OP question (just like the deleted duplicate answer) ... its possible to use it as a part of the solution but still there is a lot of work around to get to it this way ...

Comment: the solution would be to take the LCM of such int fractions and multiply the ratios with that, Do we have an prebuilt LCM function in python is another story

Answer (score 2):

**sorry not a python coder** but here is **general approach** (not bounded to a lib or language):

1. **definitions**

   so you got 2 (or `N`) floats `a,b` and want to have 2 integers `aa,bb` such that:

   ```
   a/b == aa/bb
   ```
2. **approach**

   float numbers are just integer mantissas shifted by integer exponent of base 2 to left (or right if negative exponent) so:

   ```
   a = sign(a)*mantisa(a)*2^exponent(a) = sign(a)*(mantisa(a)<<exponent(a))
   b = sign(b)*mantisa(b)*2^exponent(b) = sign(b)*(mantisa(b)<<exponent(b))
   ```

   so if we shift both `a,b` numbers so the **msb** (most significant bit) of mantissa of the bigger magnitude number will go to **msb** of some integer variable  you transformed the `a,b` into integers without changing their ratio (unless some bits of mantissa are cut of due to smaller bit-width of target variable data-type). Its like multiplying the numbers with the same constant.
3. **extract exponents from `a,b`**

   that can be simply done by directly extract the exponent bits a s integer number and substract bias from it to make it signed or by using `log2()` math function.
4. **compute `shift`**

   we need to bit shift the mantissas of `a,b` by `shift` bits or multiply `a,b` by `2^shift` so the bigger magnitude number will be biggest which still fits into integer variable. So if I assume `32` bit signed integer we want that **msb** of the bigger magnitude number will be `30` (bits are numbered from `0` and we want leave the last bit as is so we can still apply sign).

   the computation is simple:

   ```cpp
       shift=max( exponent(a), exponent(b) );
       shift=30-shift;        
   //  shift-=_f32_man_bits;   // this is just in case of bit-shifting
   ```
5. **bitshift or multiply the `a,b` and construct result**

   so simply convert `a,b` to integer as described in previous bullet. After that you can divide the resultign integers by their **GCD** or shift them right until lsb of `a` or `b` is nonzero (remove trailing zeros).

   Here small example in binary:

   ```
                      exponent(b)=2 exponent(a)=-3
                                  |     |
                                  | 0.0010101110b <- a 
                                  100.01101b      <- b
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   _f32_man_bits = 23 // 32 bit float has 24 bit mantisa but first one is implicit
   shift = 30 - max(exponent(b),exponent(a)) = 30 - 2 = 28
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ????????????????????????????????.0000000000b <- 32 bit integer variable
   00000010101110000000000000000000.0000000000b <- a * (1 << shift) = mantissa(a)|(1<<_f32_man_bits) << (shift + exponent(a) - _f32_man_bits)
   01000110100000000000000000000000.0000000000b <- b * (1 << shift) = mantissa(b)|(1<<_f32_man_bits) << (shift + exponent(b) - _f32_man_bits)
   |
   msb is zero so sign can still be applied ...
   ```

   Removing trailing zeros can be done like this:

   ```cpp
   // remove trailing zeros
   for (;((aa|bb)&1)==0;)
       {
       aa>>=1;
       bb>>=1;
       }
   ```

   the above example would change to:

   ```
   0000001010111b
   0100011010000b
   ```

   The division by **GCD** can be done like this (after removing trailing zeros):

   ```cpp
   // divide by GCD
   for (int d=3;(d<=aa)&&(d<=bb);d+=2)
    while ((aa%d)+(bb%d)==0)
     { aa/=d; bb/=d; }
   ```

   At last apply sign.

**Here C++ floating example (multiply):**

```cpp
void f32_ratio0(int &aa,int &bb,float a,float b)    // aa/bb = a/b
    {
    // IEEE 754 constants
    const DWORD _f32_man_bits=23;           // mantisa bits (without implicit one)
    // variables
    int shift,d;
    int expa,siga;
    int expb,sigb;
    // extract parts of a,b
    siga=(a<0.0); a=fabs(a);        sigb=(b<0.0); b=fabs(b);
    expa=floor(log(a)/log(2.0));    expb=floor(log(b)/log(2.0));
    // compute shift
    shift=expa; if (shift<expb) shift=expb; // max(expa,expb)
    shift=30-shift;                         // shift msb of bigger mantisa to 30th bit of integer
    // construct result
    aa=float(a*pow(2.0,shift));
    bb=float(b*pow(2.0,shift));
    // remove trailing zeros
    for (;((aa|bb)&1)==0;)
        {
        aa>>=1;
        bb>>=1;
        }
    // divide by GCD
    for (d=3;(d<=aa)&&(d<=bb);d+=2)
     while ((aa%d)+(bb%d)==0)
      { aa/=d; bb/=d; }
    // sign
    if (siga) aa=-aa;
    if (sigb) bb=-bb;
    }
```

**Here C++ integer example (shifting):**

```cpp
void f32_ratio1(int &aa,int &bb,float a,float b)    // aa/bb = a/b
    {
    // IEEE 754 constants
    const DWORD _f32_sig    =0x80000000;    // sign
    const DWORD _f32_exp    =0x7F800000;    // exponent
    const DWORD _f32_exp_sig=0x40000000;    // exponent sign
    const DWORD _f32_exp_bia=0x3F800000;    // exponent bias
    const DWORD _f32_exp_lsb=0x00800000;    // exponent LSB
    const DWORD _f32_man    =0x007FFFFF;    // mantisa
    const DWORD _f32_man_msb=0x00400000;    // mantisa MSB
    const DWORD _f32_man_bits=23;           // mantisa bits (without implicit one)
    const DWORD _f32_exp_bias=127;          // exponent bias
    // float bits access
    union
        {
        float f;        // 32bit floating point
        DWORD u;        // 32 bit uint
        } y;
    // variables
    int shift,d;
    int mana,expa,siga;
    int manb,expb,sigb;
    // extract parts of a
    y.f=a;
    mana=(y.u&_f32_man)|_f32_exp_lsb;
    expa=((y.u&_f32_exp)>>_f32_man_bits)-_f32_exp_bias;
    siga=(y.u&_f32_sig);
    // extract parts of b
    y.f=b;
    manb=(y.u&_f32_man)|_f32_exp_lsb;
    expb=((y.u&_f32_exp)>>_f32_man_bits)-_f32_exp_bias;
    sigb=(y.u&_f32_sig);
    // compute shift
    shift=expa; if (shift<expb) shift=expb; // max(expa,expb)
    shift=(30-_f32_man_bits)-shift;         // shift msb of bigger mantisa to 30th bit of integer
    // construct result
    d=shift+expa; aa=mana; if (d<0) aa>>=-d; else if (d>0) aa<<=d;
    d=shift+expb; bb=manb; if (d<0) bb>>=-d; else if (d>0) bb<<=d;
    // remove trailing zeros
    for (;((aa|bb)&1)==0;)
        {
        aa>>=1;
        bb>>=1;
        }
    // divide by GCD
    for (d=3;(d<=aa)&&(d<=bb);d+=2)
     while ((aa%d)+(bb%d)==0)
      { aa/=d; bb/=d; }
    // sign
    if (siga) aa=-aa;
    if (sigb) bb=-bb;
    }
```

where `DWORD` is any unsigned 32 bit data-type for example:

```cpp
typedef unsigned __int32 DWORD;
```

The `double` precision will be done in the same manner only the constants changes and `64bit` or `2x32bit` variables are needed to store the integer mantissas and results...

Accuracy is dependent on the relative distance of the exponents. If the numbers have too big difference the resulting numbers would not fit into target integers resulting in the smaller magnitude number converting to zero if:

```
abs( exponent(a) - exponent(b) ) >= 31
```

Again if bigger bit-widths are used for the integers the 31 will change accordingly ...

**Now your examples:**

```
//    a             b     a/b       
0.50000 /     1.00000 =   0.500000 // floats
//   aa            bb     aa/bb       
      1 /           2 =   0.500000 // ratio0
      1 /           2 =   0.500000 // ratio1

//    a             b     a/b       
0.50000 /     0.60000 =   0.833333 // floats
//   aa            bb     aa/bb       
4194304 /     5033165 =   0.833333 // ratio0
4194304 /     5033165 =   0.833333 // ratio1
```

**Note that `0.6` can not be represented by floats exactly hence big values of `aa,bb` !!!** To solve that you need to add rounding but for that you need to know the threshold that tels you what part of number to round... Without knowing the targeted range of floats or accuracy I can not implement this safely...

If you want to preserve ratio between more floats than simply add them to function.

**Here floating C++ example for 3 variables:**

```cpp
void f32_ratio0(int &aa,int &bb,int &cc,float a,float b,float c)    // aa/bb/cc = a/b/c
    {
    // IEEE 754 constants
    const DWORD _f32_man_bits=23;           // mantisa bits (without implicit one)
    // variables
    int shift,d;
    int expa,siga;
    int expb,sigb;
    int expc,sigc;
    // extract parts of a,b
    siga=(a<0.0); a=fabs(a);        sigb=(b<0.0); b=fabs(b);        sigc=(c<0.0); c=fabs(c);
    expa=floor(log(a)/log(2.0));    expb=floor(log(b)/log(2.0));    expc=floor(log(c)/log(2.0));
    // compute shift
                    shift=expa;             // max(expa,expb)
    if (shift<expb) shift=expb;
    if (shift<expc) shift=expc;
    shift=30-shift;                         // shift msb of bigger mantisa to 30th bit of integer
    // construct result
    aa=float(a*pow(2.0,shift));
    bb=float(b*pow(2.0,shift));
    cc=float(c*pow(2.0,shift));
    // remove trailing zeros
    for (;((aa|bb|cc)&1)==0;)
        {
        aa>>=1;
        bb>>=1;
        cc>>=1;
        }
    // divide by GCD
    for (d=3;(d<=aa)&&(d<=bb)&&(d<=cc);d+=2)
     while ((aa%d)+(bb%d)+(cc%d)==0)
      { aa/=d; bb/=d; cc/=d; }
    // sign
    if (siga) aa=-aa;
    if (sigb) bb=-bb;
    if (sigc) cc=-cc;
    }
```

**and your example result:**

```
//    a             b             c
0.50000 /     0.60000 /     1.00000
//   aa            bb            cc
4194304 /     5033165 /     8388608
```

**[Edit1] `N` case algorithm**

1. **extract parts of the `N` floats `O(N)`**

   so we have floats `a0,a1,a2,...,a(N-1)` and want integer exponents `e0,e1,...` and mantissas `m0,m1,...` and signs `s0,s1,...`. For 32 bit floats it would be (using // IEEE 754 constants from above examples):

   ```cpp
   int i,m[N],e[N],s[N];
   float a[N]={ ... your numbers here ... };
   unsigned __int32 *u=(unsigned __int32*)a,i;
   for (i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
    m[i]=(u[i]&_f32_man)|_f32_exp_lsb;
    a[i]=((u[i]&_f32_exp)>>_f32_man_bits)-_f32_exp_bias;
    s[i]=(u[i]&_f32_sig);
    }
   ```
2. **compute `shift` its `O(N)`**

   so first compute max of `e[i]` `O(N)` and than the `shift` itself `O(1)`

   ```cpp
   // shift = max(e[0...N-1])
   int shift;
   for (shift=e[0],i=1;i<N;i++)
    if (shift<e[i])
     shift=e[i]; 
   // shift 
   shift=30-shift;
   ```
3. **apply shift and construct result `O(N)`**

   ```
   for (i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
    int d=shift+e[i]-_f32_man_bits;
         if (d<0) m[i]>>=-d;
    else if (d>0) m[i]<<= d;
    if (s[i]) m[i]=-m[i];
    }
   ```

   the results are in `m[]`.

Comment: Ignoring for the moment your solution seems to have nothing to do with a solution written in Python. Your solution is needlessly specific to MS Windows (e.g., the use of `DWORD`) and assumes things about the, implied, `float` type for `a`, `b`, etc. What about type `double`?

Comment: @KurtisRader `double` is the same you just use 64 bit variable or 2x32 bit ... and change bias (`1023`) and bit shift (`52`) value and change the bitmasks accordingly too ... have not touch it as there is no mention about `double` precision in the OP and no this ts not MS specific (the floating equation after `if you can not access float in such manner` does not use any hacs nor DWORD ...) but yes this is not a Python directly is a generic approach for any platform/language/environment instead.

Comment: @KurtisRader I reedited my question added (still C++) example and more in depth explanations... Btw. the other two answers does not answer the OP question at all (as the OP author also states in a comment)... code examples are only to show possible implementation the core of answer is the description of the math behind ...

Answer (score 0):

The short answer, as [heemayl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56821131/8998223) mentions, is to use `.as_integer_ratio()`.

The problem with it is that sometimes, because of reasons regarding floating point precision, it returns big integers that although harder to parse by human eye are more precise.

For example:

```python
    >>> 0.25.as_integer_ratio()
    (1, 4)
    >>> 0.4.as_integer_ratio()
    (3602879701896397, 9007199254740992)
```

Great but we know that `2/5` is also `0.4`. To get around *simplifying*, you can use the `Fraction` built-in [.limit_denominator()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator) method.

In the case that you do NOT want to use the `Fraction` built-in (you really should use it), I found that this works, although I am not sure if it's equivalent to using the `Fraction` built-in.

```python
   >>> tuple(reversed((1 / 0.4).as_integer_ratio()))
   (2, 5)
```