# How to fill a fixed rectangle with square pieces entirely?

Tags: algorithm, math, knapsack-problem, packing, bin-packing

[image]

Is this knapsack algorithm or bin packing? I couldn't find an exact solution but basically I have a fixed rectangle area that I want to fill with perfect squares that represents my items where each have a different weight which will influence their size relative to others.

They will be sorted from large to smaller from top left to bottom right.

Also even though I need perfect squares, in the end some non-uniform scaling is allowed to fill the entire space as long as they still retain their relative area, and the non-uniform scaling is done with the least possible amount.

What algorithm I can use to achieve this?

Comment: I do not think perfect squares are always possible on binary computer ... more like some floating point accuracy limit like 2^-24 of rectangle size. I would compute biggest common divisor (but floating point one) of the rectangle sizes and use that as side size of square that will uniformly fill your rectangle. At first iteration we can take rectangle size float align both to the same exponent and use that mantissas as integer for the GCD. In other words scale the rectangle up so its size are integers within the precision limit

Comment: Once you got grid of squares you can merge some of them to form bigger squares if you want... see this [Converting floating ratios to int](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56822747/2521214) in there is all yo uneed to compute the GCD for any float size rectangle

Comment: This seems hard to impossible, particularly with the sorting criterion. The [packing algorithms](http://www.squaring.net/sq/tws.html) I'm aware of allow very little control of the square sizes or the aspect ratio. [Treemapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping) is easier, but perhaps you have reasons for wanting squares.

Comment: Thanks guys, what's GCD? I just found out it's called treemapping. I guess I could use that. I just thought perfect squares look better. Also in my case I don't have so many items, say maximum 100.

Comment: If you're willing to forgo the sorting, it might be possible to optimize for a tree that would result in a treemap with close to 1:1 aspect ratios.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I think that might be ok. But WPF doesnt have a control right? So that means making my own or 3rd party?

Comment: @JoanVenge I'm unfamiliar with WPF, but probably?

Comment: Actually if WPF lets you specify the tree, then you shouldn't need a new control.

Comment: @JoanVenge GCD means Greatest Common Divisor ... if your rectangle is of integer size `a,b` then square `size = GCD(a,b);` which will fit your rectangle ... if you got float size then you need to use the approach from the QA I linked ...

Comment: @JoanVenge btw what exactly is the input? I assume rectangle size (which you still did not clarify if integer or floating) ... what else (number of items? items area? any constraints)?

Comment: @Spektre: I want to do something like this for the coins I hold: https://mlnqhjoxgxmy.i.optimole.com/dgsaIJs-vpySYn_M/w:800/h:515/q:auto/https://hodlhard.io/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/coin360-coinmap-visualization.png As for rectangle size, it doesn't matter float or int as long as I can draw these in WPF. Number of items max 100, more likely 20-50. Area could be 1000x1000 pixels but if it could adapt it different sizes could be good for say 1500x1000, but nothing super small.

Comment: @Spektre No other constrains other than everything should be as close to squares as they can be and also if possible the sorting should be from top left to bottom right from largest to smallest. like those images i sent. If you google crypto market cap map, you can see many variations they dont try to be squares but that's what i thought would be cool.

Answer (score 5):

There's a [fast approximation algorithm](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.dam.2006.08.005) due to Hiroshi Nagamochi and Yuusuke Abe. I implemented it in C++, taking care to obtain a worst-case O(n log n)-time implementation with worst-case recursive depth O(log n). If n ≤ 100, these precautions are probably unnecessary.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

namespace {

struct Rectangle {
  double x;
  double y;
  double width;
  double height;
};

Rectangle Slice(Rectangle &r, const double beta) {
  const double alpha = 1 - beta;
  if (r.width > r.height) {
    const double alpha_width = alpha * r.width;
    const double beta_width = beta * r.width;
    r.width = alpha_width;
    return {r.x + alpha_width, r.y, beta_width, r.height};
  }
  const double alpha_height = alpha * r.height;
  const double beta_height = beta * r.height;
  r.height = alpha_height;
  return {r.x, r.y + alpha_height, r.width, beta_height};
}

void LayoutRecursive(const std::vector<double> &reals, const std::size_t begin,
                     std::size_t end, double sum, Rectangle rectangle,
                     std::vector<Rectangle> &dissection) {
  while (end - begin > 1) {
    double suffix_sum = reals[end - 1];
    std::size_t mid = end - 1;
    while (mid > begin + 1 && suffix_sum + reals[mid - 1] <= 2 * sum / 3) {
      suffix_sum += reals[mid - 1];
      mid -= 1;
    }
    LayoutRecursive(reals, mid, end, suffix_sum,
                    Slice(rectangle, suffix_sum / sum), dissection);
    end = mid;
    sum -= suffix_sum;
  }
  dissection.push_back(rectangle);
}

std::vector<Rectangle> Layout(std::vector<double> reals,
                              const Rectangle rectangle) {
  std::sort(reals.begin(), reals.end());
  std::vector<Rectangle> dissection;
  dissection.reserve(reals.size());
  LayoutRecursive(reals, 0, reals.size(),
                  std::accumulate(reals.begin(), reals.end(), double{0}),
                  rectangle, dissection);
  return dissection;
}

std::vector<double> RandomReals(const std::size_t n) {
  std::vector<double> reals(n);
  std::exponential_distribution<> dist;
  std::default_random_engine gen;
  for (double &real : reals) {
    real = dist(gen);
  }
  return reals;
}

} // namespace

int main() {
  const std::vector<Rectangle> dissection =
      Layout(RandomReals(100), {72, 72, 6.5 * 72, 9 * 72});
  std::cout << "%!PS\n";
  for (const Rectangle &r : dissection) {
    std::cout << r.x << " " << r.y << " " << r.width << " " << r.height
              << " rectstroke\n";
  }
  std::cout << "showpage\n";
}
```

[image]

Comment: does not look like squares

Comment: @Spektre "some non-uniform scaling is allowed"

Comment: citing the OP: `the non-uniform scaling is done with the least possible amount` I see no squares in your output ...

Comment: @Spektre This seems like a hard problem. Feel free to post your own answer.

Comment: I would but there is a lot of clarification of input missing and without it Its a waste of time to answer and then realize OP author wanted different combination of inputs ... Also looks like (s)he is also missing the required math skills for this (assuming from the question about what GCD is) despite of high rep... but it might be just too diferent language ... I often do not understand some math in English on occasion as it uses different notations

Answer (score 2):

Ok so lets assume integer positions and sizes (no float operations). To evenly divide rectangle into regular square grid (as big squares as possible) the size of the cells will be greatest common divisor **GCD** of the rectangle sizes.

However you want to have much less squares than that so I would try something like this:

1. **try all square sizes `a` from 1 to smaller size of rectangle**
2. **for each `a` compute the naive square grid size of the rest of rectangle once  `a*a` square is cut of it**

   so its simply GCD again on the 2 rectangles that will be created once `a*a` square is cut of. If the min of all 3 sizes `a` and GCD for the 2 rectangles is bigger than 1 (ignoring zero area rectangles) then consider `a` as valid solution so remember it.
3. **after the `for` loop use last found valid`a`**

   so simply add `a*a` square to your output and recursively do this whole again for the 2 rectangles that will remain from your original rectangle after `a*a` square was cut off.

**Here simple C++/VCL/OpenGL example for this:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit1.h"
#include "gl_simple.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class square                // simple square
    {
public:
    int x,y,a;              // corner 2D position and size
    square(){ x=y=a=0.0; }
    square(int _x,int _y,int _a){ x=_x; y=_y; a=_a; }
    ~square(){}
    void draw()
        {
        glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        glVertex2i(x  ,y);
        glVertex2i(x+a,y);
        glVertex2i(x+a,y+a);
        glVertex2i(x  ,y+a);
        glEnd();
        }
    };
int rec[4]={20,20,760,560}; // x,y,a,b
const int N=1024;           // max square number
int n=0;                    // number of squares
square s[N];                // squares
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int gcd(int a,int b)        // slow euclid GCD
    {
    if(!b) return a;
    return gcd(b, a % b);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void compute(int x0,int y0,int xs,int ys)
    {
    if ((xs==0)||(ys==0)) return;
    const int x1=x0+xs;
    const int y1=y0+ys;
    int a,b,i,x,y;
    square t;
    // try to find biggest square first
    for (a=1,b=0;(a<=xs)&&(a<=ys);a++)
        {
        // sizes for the rest of the rectangle once a*a square is cut of
        if (xs==a) x=0; else x=gcd(a,xs-a);
        if (ys==a) y=0; else y=gcd(a,ys-a);
        // min of all sizes
                          i=a;
        if ((x>0)&&(i>x)) i=x;
        if ((y>0)&&(i>y)) i=y;
        // if divisible better than by 1 remember it as better solution
        if (i>1) b=a;
        } a=b;
    // bigger square not found so use naive square grid division
    if (a<=1)
        {
        t.a=gcd(xs,ys);
        for (t.y=y0;t.y<y1;t.y+=t.a)
         for (t.x=x0;t.x<x1;t.x+=t.a)
          if (n<N){ s[n]=t; n++; }
        }
    // bigest square found so add it to result and recursively process the rest
    else{
        t=square(x0,y0,a);
        if (n<N){ s[n]=t; n++; }
        compute(x0+a,y0,xs-a,a);
        compute(x0,y0+a,xs,ys-a);
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gl_draw()
    {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // set view to 2D [pixel] units
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(-1.0,-1.0,0.0);
    glScalef(2.0/float(xs),2.0/float(ys),1.0);

    // render input rectangle
    glColor3f(0.2,0.2,0.2);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2i(rec[0]       ,rec[1]);
    glVertex2i(rec[0]+rec[2],rec[1]);
    glVertex2i(rec[0]+rec[2],rec[1]+rec[3]);
    glVertex2i(rec[0]       ,rec[1]+rec[3]);
    glEnd();

    // render output squares
    glColor3f(0.2,0.5,0.9);
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) s[i].draw();

    glFinish();
    SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
    {
    // Init of program
    gl_init(Handle);    // init OpenGL
    n=0; compute(rec[0],rec[1],rec[2],rec[3]);
    Caption=n;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    // Exit of program
    gl_exit();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
    {
    // repaint
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
    {
    // resize
    gl_resize(ClientWidth,ClientHeight);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**And preview for the actually hardcoded rectangle:**

[image: preview]

The number 8 in Caption of the window is the number of squares produced.

Beware this is just very simple startup example for this problem. I Have not tested it extensively so there is possibility once prime sizes or just unlucky aspect ratios are involved then this might result in really high number of squares... for example if GCD of the rectangle size is 1 (primes) ... In such case you should tweak the initial rectangle size (+/-1 or whatever)

The important thing in the code is just the `compute()` function and the global variables holding the output squares `s[n]`... beware the `compute()` does not clear the list (in order to allow recursion) so you need to set `n=0` before its non recursive call.

To keep this simple I avoided to use any libs or dynamic allocations or containers for the compute itself...

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try to port this to C#. But would this allow me to pass a list of items that represents weights for each square? (Normalized or not) So for example so that I can have boxes with weights like 1, 5, 10, 20 and they would be represented properly relative to their weight.

Comment: @JoanVenge what you mean by weight? if just value that should be displayed then yes ,,, if area then no as that is huge constraint that you did not mention before so algo did not include such things ... That is why I asked for the input ... and your vague response results in problems like this  ...

Comment: Oh sorry I put in the OP like this: "represents my items where each have a different weight which will influence their size relative to others" Basically all those weight values, their sum would be the total area of the entire space that will host the squares. And each square would use an area in proportion to its weight, so a weight value of 2 would have twice bigger area than a weight value of 1. Is this hard to add?

Comment: @JoanVenge share **specific** sample input !

Comment: The sample input is the coin holdings that I have, so the more holdings I have in USD value, the bigger the area they occupy in the treemap similar to the image I posted in the comments about crypto market cap treemap where the area represents the market cap.

Comment: @JoanVenge That is not specific input ... If you reluctant even to create simple single sample input how you expect others to answer

Comment: I explained everything in the OP and comments. I don't know how else you want me to describe it.