# Finding ratio of 2 numbers in C++

Tags: c++, math

I'm currently learning C++ using PPP by Bjarne Stroustrup. There is a Practice question:

> Write a program that prompts the user to enter two integer values.
> Store these values in int variables named val1 and val2. Write your
> program to determine the smaller, larger, sum, difference, product, and
> **ratio** of these values and report them to the user.

For ratio I want it to be like `The ratio of 500 and 700 is 5:7`. I known the answer of this could be

```
double ratio = 500/700;
```

But I want to show this as `5:7` rather than `500/700 = 0.714`.

How can I do that?

Edit: - That's how I did it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

void Ratio(double val1, double val2)
{
    double temp1 = val1;
    double temp2 = val2;
    for(int num = 0; num < 20; num++)
    {
        if(num == 0 || num == 1)
            continue;

        if(std::fmod(temp1, num) == 0 && std::fmod(temp1, num) == 0) 
        {
            temp1 /= num;
            temp1 /= num;
            num = 0;
        }
    } 
    std::cout<<"Ratio of " << val1 << " and " << val2 << " is " << val1 << ":" << val2<< std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Ratio(500, 700);
}
```

I'm still a beginner in programming and this really is something for me.
Anyone have a better solution for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting floating ratios to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56821119/converting-floating-ratios-to-int)

Comment: You can divide (integer?) `val1` and `val2` by their [`gcd`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd) to simplify the expression.

Comment: The task asks you to enter *integer* values and you are working with `double` precision *floating* point numbers, so I would not consider this as valid. If you wanted a formally valid solution, you would have to consider Euclid's algorithm, which however is certainly not the task here.

Comment: Note that `double ratio = 500/700;` will set double `ratio` to `0`.

Comment: Since C++17, `std::gcd(500,700) == 100`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Dominique points out:

> You are working with the wrong algorithm: In order to find the ratio
> between two numbers `a` and `b`, you are doing:
>
> ```
> calculate a/b; 
> do something with the result.
> ```
>
> This does not work, as
> computers don't understand rational numbers (in mathematics, `1/3` is
> different from `0.333333333`, but for a computer both are equal because
> computer cannot handle infinite decimals).

What you want is to [simplified a fraction](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reduce-the-fraction-to-its-lowest-form/) (reducing it to the simplest form). To do this, you can divide both `a` and `b` by `gcd(a,b)`. `gcd()` of two numbers can be calculated with [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), or by using directly the [`__gcd()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd).

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if (b == 0) {return a;}
    return gcd(b, a%b);
}

pair<int, int> ratioFunc(int a, int b)
{
    pair<int, int> ret;
    if (a == 0)
    {
        ret.first = 0; ret.second = b;
    }
    else
    {
        int gc = gcd(abs(a),abs(b));
        a /= gc; b /= gc;
        ret.first = a; ret.second = b;
    }
    return ret;

}

int main()
{
    int a,b; cin >> a >> b;
    if (b == 0) {cout << "No answer";}
    else {auto res = ratioFunc(a,b); cout << "The ratio of " << a << " and " << b << " is " << res.first << ":" << res.second;}
}
```

Output :

```
500 700
The ratio of 500 and 700 is 5:7
```

Output (with negative integers):

```
-33 27
The ratio of -33 and 27 is -11:9
```

In case you haven't worked with `pair` yet, you can simply print immediately:

```
void ratioFunc(int a, int b)
{
    if (b == 0) {cout << "No answer";}
    else
    {

        if (a == 0) {cout << "The ratio of " << a << " and " << b << " is " << a << ":" << b; return; }

        int x = a, y = b; //Storing a,b for printing
        int gc = gcd(abs(a),abs(b));
        a /= gc; b /= gc;

        cout << "The ratio of " << x << " and " << y << " is " << a << ":" << b;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am just starting out in c++ and currently don't know about algortihm. your answer is helpful for me.

Comment: I just re-read my answer and I realise my mistake: the correct abbreviation is "gcd", from "Greatest Common Dividor", and not "ggd" from "Grootste Gemene Deler" (I have Dutch as mother tongue) :-)

Comment: @Dominique I noticed it but I just assumed it's some form of `gcd`. For example, in my country student actually call it hcf more instead of gcd :)

Answer (score 3):

You are working with the wrong algorithm: in order to find the ratio between two numbers `a` and `b`, you are doing:

```
calculate a/b;
do something with the result.
```

This does not work, as computers don't understand rational numbers (in mathematics, `1/3 is different from 0.333333333`, but for a computer both are equal because computer cannot handle infinite decimals).

Therefore you need to adopt another algorithm, which is the following:

```
calculate the greatest common divisor of a and b (ggd(a,b))
Show: a / ggd(a,b)
      b / ggd(a,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by many pals here, you could use the gcd <strike>to find-and-devide steps in a loop untill the gcd is 1</strike>, but it may not be optimal.

I think an optimal algorithm would be factoring both numbers and remove the common factors, then multiply the remaining factors and print out them for each number.

A pseudocode would look like this:

```
1. input a and b
2. list a_factors := all factors of a
3. list b_factors := all factors of b
4. subprog: remove common elements in a_factors and b_factors
5. let a := multiplication of all remaining elements in a_factors
6. let b := multiplication of all remaining elements in b_factors
7. output a and b
```

Comment: The `gcd`-approach is not some iterative scheme. The greatest common divisor is computed _once_, and dividing that out immediately reduces the ratio to its lowest terms.

Comment: @N.Wouda, thank you for the hint, apparently I was wrong thinking that gcd returns the greatest factor, so I've adjusted my answer. Nevertheless, I think the gcd approach may be somewhat not optimal, but still very short and powerful to accomplish the problem.

Comment: One way to find out would be to benchmark both approaches. But I am very skeptical this approach - with a complete factorization of both numbers - outperforms one application of Euclid's algorithm for anything but the smallest integers.

Comment: @N.Wouda, I agree that a benchmark would speak loud, but I think this algorithm would at least be not worse than gcd since it has no flaws, while gcd is itself complicated already, with lots of multiplications and divisions.

Comment: Compare for example [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm), or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve). I think you will find most algorithms for integer factorization include, as you say, lots of multiplications and divisions.